# Way To Store Global Meta Values

Tags: custom-field

When using posts there is a way to store meta values on a per post level. Is there a way to store values on a global site value? I want to save a numeric value that isnt tied to any single post.

I was thinking i could just do something like

```
get_post_meta( 0, 'somevalue', true );
```

This will work, but it will still be storing the value as a post field. is there anything specific that was designed for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is [Option API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API) to store site global data.

You can store some global values using [`add_option()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option) then can retrive values as [`get_option()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option)

**Example:**

```
add_option( 'option_name', 'option_value', 'deprecated', 'yes' );
//OR
update_option('option_name', 'option_value', 'yes');


//Get the value
$your_data = get_option('option_name', 'option_default_value');
echo $your_data;
```

Comment: i am in a position where i will need to be creating one new field a day and adding onto it as the day goes on. will calling update create a field if it does not exist already?

Comment: Yes, exactly if field does exist it calls `add_option()`.